# Find a word in excel file in Rapidminer

Tags: rapidminer

I have Process that read a text file and have a operator **Process Document from Data** Operator that have **Tokenize** operator.

It work normally but when I change the source of **Process Document from Data** to Read Excel, the output is empty. I think that I have mistake and the **Read Excel** operator can not connect to **Process Document from Data** directly and must read every column of Excel file and then connect to **Process Document from Data**.

Anybody can help me how I connect Excel file from **Process Document from Data**?

PS: My goal is read excel file and show the word that repeat in column of excel file more that 3 times.

Sample file is: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't include your process or input data, may I simply suggest an alternative without Documents at all?

If your goal is to find entries in a specific column of an Excel file, you can do this in three operators: **Read Excel**, **Aggregate** and **Filter Examples**:

Use **Read Excel** to extract the column as an example set with a single attribute (e.g. *words*), **Aggregate** the *words* attribute with the *count* function and also group by *words* (this gives you your desired count per word) and finally use **Filter Examples** to only keep words with a count of 3 or more.

Example process (re-run the import configuration wizard for your specific setup):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><process version="9.0.003">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="9.0.003" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="read_excel" compatibility="9.0.003" expanded="true" height="68" name="Read Excel" width="90" x="45" y="34">
        <parameter key="excel_file" value="D:\words.xlsx"/>
        <parameter key="imported_cell_range" value="A1:A100"/>
        <list key="annotations"/>
        <parameter key="date_format" value="MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a z"/>
        <list key="data_set_meta_data_information">
          <parameter key="0" value="words.true.polynominal.attribute"/>
        </list>
        <parameter key="read_not_matching_values_as_missings" value="false"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="aggregate" compatibility="9.0.003" expanded="true" height="82" name="Aggregate" width="90" x="179" y="34">
        <list key="aggregation_attributes">
          <parameter key="words" value="count"/>
        </list>
        <parameter key="group_by_attributes" value="words"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="filter_examples" compatibility="9.0.003" expanded="true" height="103" name="Filter Examples" width="90" x="313" y="34">
        <list key="filters_list">
          <parameter key="filters_entry_key" value="count(words).ge.3"/>
        </list>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Read Excel" from_port="output" to_op="Aggregate" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Aggregate" from_port="example set output" to_op="Filter Examples" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Filter Examples" from_port="example set output" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 3" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Comment: I add some sample of my excel file in question....when i run the process the output is empty...i think i must change attribute "Word"

Comment: Yes, in my example "words" is the column header, which is used as the attribute name.